# Task.Factory.StartNew - ContinueWith using .Wait()

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, taskfactory

I am declaring a task using TaskFactory, and I have a serious doubt.

I am creating the task declaring the continueWith on creation, I am not assigning
it too a second task who will be started later.

The declaration is like this:

```
Dim taskConta = Tasks.Task(Of DataSet).Factory.StartNew(
                Function() FunctionToLaunch(parameter), TokenCancel.Token,  Tasks.TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)

taskConta.ContinueWith(New Action(Sub() Throw New TimeoutException("Exception Error"), System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

As you can see. This task is declared with :

> TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted

The task is executed and then my next line of code is:

```
 taskConta.Wait()
```

The question is:

If my task exits faulted and I have used `.Wait()`.
 Will the ContinueWith Action be started before the code continues execution?
 Or would it be queued and started later?

If it is started later, How long would it take more or less?
 That could do that my `Throw Exception` could be launched out of the scope.

I know I could do something like:

```
  taskConta.Wait()

  If taskConta.Status <> Tasks.TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
         Throw New TimeoutException("Message")
  End If
```

Would I would like to know how the TaskFactory continueWith queue works.

Answer (score 0):

> If my task exits faulted and I have used `.Wait()`. Will the ContinueWith Action be started before the code continues execution? Or would it be queued and started later?

The two actions (the `ContinueWith()` method starting and the `Wait()`ing thread resuming) can happen in any order. All you can be sure about is that they both happen only after the `taskConta` `Task` completes.

If you want to wait until the continuation completes, you can do that by waiting on the `Task` returned from `ContinueWith()`.

---

But you also seem to be confused about how `Task` behave with regards to exceptions. What you're doing in your continuation is a bad idea. In .Net 4.5, it won't do anything, because exceptions from unobserved `Task`s are ignored there. In .Net 4.0, the exception is going to be thrown when the continuation `Task` is finalized, which means it will happen at some unspecified point in the future and you can't use a normal `Catch` to deal with the exception.

Also, if you `Wait()` on a faulted exception, `Wait()` throws the exception enclosed in `AggregateException`. This means if you want to handle a specific exception from the `Task`, you can use `Catch`. For example:

```
Try
    taskConta.Wait()
Catch e as AggregateException
    If TypeOf e.InnerException Is SomeSpecificException
        Throw New TimeoutException("message", e.InnerException)
    Else
        Throw
    End If
End Try
```